# Rails Refresh renders the "show" action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, refresh

I've got a custom action titled "details." When the user refreshes the screen, the screen tries to render the "show" action. What might be causing this? How can I cause the refresh to reload the "details" action?

Controller Action:

```
  def details
    @extent = params[:extent]
    @label = Label.find(params[:label])
    @style = params[:style]
    create_question_group
  end

  def create_question_group
    @question_group = []
    5.times do
       @question_group << Question.new
     end
  end
```

Views/Questions/details.html.erb

```
<% provide(:title, 'New Questions') %>
<% provide(:headerText, "Details for New Questions") %>
<% provide(:headerPic, 'question.png') %>

<%= render 'shared/back-link' %>
<%= render 'shared/headline' %>

<div class="singleOption">
    <h3><%= @extent.capitalize %> <%= @style.capitalize %> Questions &emsp;&emsp; Label: <%= @label.name %></h3>
</div>
</br>

<%= form_tag create_group_questions_path do %>
    <% @question_group.each_with_index do |question, index| %>
        <%= hidden_field_tag "questions[#{index.to_i}][extent]", @extent %>
        <%= hidden_field_tag "questions[#{index.to_i}][label_id]", @label.id %>
        <%= hidden_field_tag "questions[#{index.to_i}][style]", @style %>
        <% @question = question %>
        <%= render 'prompt_and_answers', :locals =>{:index => index, :style => @style} %>
        </br>
    <% end %>

    <div class="actions">
        <%= submit_tag "Create These Questions" %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Config/routes.rb

```
root   'static_pages#home'
get    '/help',    to: 'static_pages#help'
get    '/about',   to: 'static_pages#about'
get    '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact'
get    '/partner', to: 'static_pages#partner'
get   '/materials', to: 'static_pages#materials', :as => "materials"
get    '/signup',  to: 'teachers#new'
get    '/login',   to: 'sessions#new'
post   '/login',   to: 'sessions#create'
delete '/logout',  to: 'sessions#destroy'

resources :admins
resources :account_activations, only: [:edit]
resources :consultancies, only: [:new, :create, :show, :index]
resources :labels
resources :label_objectives do
  post 'update_quantities', on: :collection
end
resources :objective_seminars do
  post 'update_pretests', on: :collection
  post 'update_priorities', on: :collection
end
resources :objective_students
resources :objectives do
  get 'quantities', on: :member
end
resources :password_resets, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update]
resources :pictures
resources :preconditions
resources :questions do
  post 'details', on: :collection
  post 'create_group', on: :collection
end
resources :quizzes
resources :ripostes
resources :seminars do
  get 'pretests', on: :member
  get 'priorities', on: :member
  get 'scoresheet', on: :member
  get 'student_view', on: :member
end
resources :seminar_students do
  get 'removeFromClass', on: :member
  put 'ajaxUpdate', on: :member
end
resources :students do
  get 'edit_teaching_requests', on: :member
end
resources :teachers
```

Rake Routes:

```
               details_questions POST   /questions/details(.:format)                    questions#details
          create_group_questions POST   /questions/create_group(.:format)               questions#create_group
                       questions GET    /questions(.:format)                            questions#index
                                 POST   /questions(.:format)                            questions#create
                    new_question GET    /questions/new(.:format)                        questions#new
                   edit_question GET    /questions/:id/edit(.:format)                   questions#edit
                        question GET    /questions/:id(.:format)                        questions#show
                                 PATCH  /questions/:id(.:format)                        questions#update
                                 PUT    /questions/:id(.:format)                        questions#update
                                 DELETE /questions/:id(.:format)                        questions#destroy
```

Thank you in advance for any insight.

Comment: Can you run ````$ rake routes```` and post it please

Comment: I updated to include the rake routes results from the questions controller. Let me know if you think the whole list of routes is necessary. (It's almost a hundred routes long)

Comment: Can you also add the code from the ````create_question_group```` method too please. Is there a redirect in that method?

Comment: It may be because your `/questions/details(.:format)` route is `POST` instead of `GET`. Which, if that's the case, the controller is probably assuming that the `details` portion of the url is an `:id` and routing it to the show action. Can you post your routes file?

Comment: Updated again. The create_question_group method is in the same box as the controller. The config/routes files is above the rake results. It makes sense that a post route could be causing this problem. But if I'm using a form_tag to submit params, don't I need a post for that?